# Use LINQ Query Operations

Tags: sql-server, linq

Please need assistance to convert this SQl Query to LINQ Query

```
SELECT EconCode.EconCodeId, 
       EconCode.EconCodeName, 
       EconCode.EconIncomeAmt, 
       EconCode.EconRecExpAmt, 
       EconCode.EconCapExpAmt, 
       FundCode.FundCodeId
FROM EconCode 
LEFT OUTER JOIN FundCode 
   ON EconCode.FundCodeId = FundCode.FundCodeId
GROUP BY EconCode.EconCodeId, 
         EconCode.EconCodeName, 
         EconCode.EconIncomeAmt, 
         EconCode.EconRecExpAmt, 
         EconCode.EconCapExpAmt, 
         FundCode.FundCodeId
```

I have tried the following codes before but but in my report display nothing.

```
var query = from econ in _context.EconCode
         join fund in _context.FundCode on econ.FundCodeId equals fund.FundCodeId
         group new { econ, fund.FundCodeId } by new { fund.FundCodeName, econ.FundCodeId, econ.EconCodeId, econ.EconCodeName, econ.EconIncomeAmt, econ.EconRecExpAmt, econ.EconCapExpAmt  } into g
          select new
             {
              fundcodeId = g.Key.FundCodeId,
              fundCodeName = g.Key.FundCodeName,
              econCodeId = g.Key.EconCodeId,
              econCodeName = g.Key.EconCodeName,
              econIncomeAmt = g.Key.EconIncomeAmt,
              econRecExpAmt = g.Key.EconRecExpAmt,
              econCapExpAmt = g.Key.EconCapExpAmt,
          };
```

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried... this is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that there are two corresponding entity classes named EconCode and FundCode, and the context variable is dbContext, The equivalent LINQ query to the SQL query provided would be:

```
var query = from econ in dbContext.EconCode
            join fund in dbContext.FundCode on econ.FundCodeId equals fund.FundCodeId into joinedGroup
            from fund in joinedGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
            group new { econ, fund } by new { econ.EconCodeId, econ.EconCodeName, econ.EconIncomeAmt, econ.EconRecExpAmt, econ.EconCapExpAmt, FundCodeId = (int?)fund.FundCodeId } into g
            select new {
                g.Key.EconCodeId,
                g.Key.EconCodeName,
                g.Key.EconIncomeAmt,
                g.Key.EconRecExpAmt,
                g.Key.EconCapExpAmt,
                FundCodeId = g.Key.FundCodeId ?? 0
            };
```